# included_list(List1, List2)

Tags: prolog

`included_list` is true when `list1` is part of `list2`.

For example,

```
included_list([1,2],[1,2,3,4]) is true. 
included_list([2,1],[1,2,3,4]) is false.
included_list([],[1,2,3,4]) is false.
included_list([1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,3,4]) is false.
```

What predicate should I write in order to get this answers?

I have tried this:

```
included_list([Head],List).

included_list([Head1|Tail1],[Head2|Tail2]) :-
                    member(Head1,[Head2]),included_list(Tail1, Tail2).
```

But it returns true when I ask `included_list([1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,3,4])`

If it is possible I want to do it without built-in libraries.

Comment: Why is `included_list([], [1, 2, 3, 4])`  false?

Comment: I just want to make that this way.

Comment: Will this work? `subseq(L1, L2) :- append(T, _, L2), append(_, L1, T).`

Comment: @rajashekar I like it, although OP wants `subseq([], _)` to fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
starts_with([H], [H|_]).
starts_with([H|T1], [H|T2]) :- starts_with(T1, T2).

included_list(X, Y) :- starts_with(X, Y).
included_list(X, [_|T]) :- included_list(X, T).
```

Tests:

```
?- included_list([], [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]).
false.

?- included_list([2, X], [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]).
X = 3 ;
X = 1 ;
false.
```

---

**Version 2**, riffing off @rajashekar's code:

```
included_list([X|Y], L2) :- append(T, _, L2), append(_, [X|Y], T).
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [dcg](/questions/tagged/dcg)!

```
included_list(Substr, Seq) :-
   Substr = [_|_],
   phrase( ( ..., seq(Substr), ... ), Seq).

... --> [] | [_], ... .

seq([]) --> [].
seq([E|Es]) -->
   [E],
   seq(Es).
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i want to make it without built in libraries if that is possible

Comment: @Giannis_00:  You are using yourself member/2 which is a built-in too ...

Comment: You are right but i would prefer to do it with another way, i just post this way because i want to be more understood the question

Answer (score 0):

1- **include1** predicate creates all possible subsets of List2, it then checks if List1 is among those subsets. If yes, then it is present in the list2, if not, then it isn't.

2- For creating the subsets **splitSet, permute and omit** predicates are used.

```
include1([H1|T1],[H2|T2]):-
    splitSet([H2|T2],_,Sublist),
    Sublist=[_|_], %disallowing empty list
    permute(Sublist,M),
    [H1|T1]=M.

splitSet([ ],[ ],[ ]).
splitSet([H|T],[H|L],R) :-
    splitSet(T,L,R).
splitSet([H|T],L,[H|R]) :-
    splitSet(T,L,R).

permute([ ],[ ]) :- !.
permute(L,[X|R]) :-
    omit(X,L,M),
    permute(M,R).

omit(H,[H|T],T).
omit(X,[H|L],[H|R]) :-
    omit(X,L,R).
```

**Examples with your test cases:**

```
?-include1([4,5],[1,2,3]).
false

?-include1([1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,2,3,4]).
false

?-include1([1,2],[1,2,3,4]).
true
false

?-include1([],[1,2,3,4]).
false
```

For this case ([2,1],[1,2,3,4]) it is giving true as [1,2,3,4] will generate a subset with [2,1].

Comment: thank you for you answer :), now i try to find a way to give false for ([2,1],[1,2,3,4])

Comment: @Giannis_00 No problem :)